# form onsubmit javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

Im making registration form with javascript validation.

```
<form name="registration" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_registration()">
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo @$_POST['username'];?>" onblur="checkUsername(this.value)">
<span id="e_username" style="display: none; color: #c00;"><?php echo _("Some error");?></span>
<input type="submit" name="register_frm_smbt" value="<?php echo _("Submit");?>">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkUsername(login){
    reg = /^[\w]{1}+[\w\.\d-_]{1,}$/i;
    if (login.length < 3 || !login.match(reg)) {
        document.getElementById("e_username").style.display = "inline";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("e_username").style.display = "none";
        return true;
    }
  }

function validate_registration(){
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      alert(username); // works
      if (checkUsername(username) ){
              alert("OK!"); //never
              return true;
              }
      else {
          alert("NOT OK!"); //never
          return false;
      }
  }
</script>
```

so `checkUsername(login)` works fine "onblur" while form filling. But `validate_registration()` doesn't. Im geting the first alert with username, but neither "OK!" or "NOT OK!" are alerting. why is that?

Comment: As a stylistic comments, when you return from an `if` statement, using `else` is extraneous. Just delete it and the code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Using the onsubmit, you're not cancelling the event, so the form get submitted and the page is reloaded.

To prevent the form from being sent to server, capture the event passed to the callback then prevent the default action like so: `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: `return validate_registration()` should indeed prevent form submission.